# Simpson's Rule returning 0

Tags: python, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

I coded a function for Simpson's Rule of numerical integration. For values of `n` more than or equal to 34, the function returns 0.

Here, `n` is the number of intervals, `a` is the start point, and `b` is the end point.

```
import math

def simpsons(f, a,b,n):
    x = []
    h = (b-a)/n
    for i in range(n+1):
        x.append(a+i*h)

    I=0
    for i in range(1,(n/2)+1):

        I+=f(x[2*i-2])+4*f(x[2*i-1])+f(x[2*i])
    return I*(h/3)

def func(x):
    return (x**(3/2))/(math.cosh(x))



x = []
print(simpsons(func,0,100,34))
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I also coded a function for the Trapezoidal Method and that does not return 0 even when `n` = 50. What is going on here?

Comment: I edited the code for readability

Comment: What version of Python are you using and can you give some example inputs that are problematic? (Also you should usually prefer editing your question with updates rather than comments.)

Comment: I am using python 2.7.5, and the output for the code above is 0.0
print(simpsons(func,0,100,34))

Comment: You're probably getting bitten by floor division. The norm in Python 2 is to divide two integers and truncate the result (throw away the decimal part). Even though your final output is a float, I bet somewhere you have a fraction like `2/3` which becomes `0` in Python 2.

Comment: How should I overcome this?

Comment: At least one of the operands must be a float. If you are using literals, you can do this by adding a decimal point: `2` is an integer while `2.` and `2.0` are floats. With variables, you just have to cast: `float(a)`. If you need more precise results and to avoid floating point errors, you can use the built-in [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) library.

Comment: Turn one of the numbers into a float, e.g. `3./2` or `h/3.` (note the dot after the `3`).

Comment: hmm python 3 seems to give me an answer around 2, but changing (h/3) to (h/3.) only gives me 1.7?

Comment: Are you forcing float division for all instances of division? Because I see several.

Comment: Im just using python 3 now...

Comment: That's probably the best solution.

Comment: The error probably already is (or was) in the computation of `h` since by automatic type recognition all of `a,b,n` are read as integers. Adding decimal dots is always recommended.

Comment: @Daniel You probably only caught one instance of floor division in the instance where you got `1.7`. As you've already noticed, one of the changes in Py3k is to include a more natural division ("true division") by default. The latter obeys the principle of least astonishment with respect to all users, rather than only C programmers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has the code for Simpson's rule in Python :

```
from __future__ import division  # Python 2 compatibility
import math

def simpson(f, a, b, n):
    """Approximates the definite integral of f from a to b by the
    composite Simpson's rule, using n subintervals (with n even)"""

    if n % 2:
        raise ValueError("n must be even (received n=%d)" % n)

    h = (b - a) / n
    s = f(a) + f(b)

    for i in range(1, n, 2):
        s += 4 * f(a + i * h)
    for i in range(2, n-1, 2):
        s += 2 * f(a + i * h)

    return s * h / 3

def func(x):
    return (x**(3/2))/(math.cosh(x))
```

Comment: Nice and much more readable. `from __future__ import division` makes Python 2's division behave like Python 3's out of the box: that is, use "true division" rather than floor division.